# How to enable the "service name" field in Apache Ranger's audits?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-ranger

Is it possible to enable the **"service name"** field in Apache Ranger's audits ?

This field is mentioned at:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Apache+Ranger+0.5+-+User+Guide#ApacheRanger0.5-UserGuide-Audit

If yes, does it depend on the version of Ranger installed, or is there a configuration file that needs to be edited ?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

It looks like the repo/repoType fields correspond to the Service Name/Type in the Apache Ranger Web UI. Can anyone confirm, please ?